# AttributeError: 'Screen' object has no attribute 'text' in Python KivyMD

Tags: python-3.x, drop-down-menu, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

***Python 3.9.0***

***KivyMD 0.104.2.dev0***

### Expected Goal

So I want to clear some MDChips depending on whether the chip's text is present in a list called **list1**, But doing so gives the following error

### Problem

I keep getting an error when I try to access the Widget tree using the `def clear(self)` functions but I keep getting the above mentioned error

I have found that using `Screen :` in the following kv string gives me the above mentioned error (mentioned in the title).

```
button = '''
Screen:
    MDRaisedButton:
        id: button_id
        text: "PRESS ME"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .35, "center_y": .8}
        on_release: app.drop.open()
'''
```

However if I remove `Screen :`, then for some reason, MDDropDownMenu widget when called using `open()` throws the following error :

> AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__ getattr __'

### Code

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivymd.uix.chip import MDChip
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

button = '''
Screen:
    MDRaisedButton:
        id: button_id
        text: "PRESS ME"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .35, "center_y": .8}
        on_release: app.drop.open()
'''

button1 = '''
Screen:
    MDRaisedButton:
        id: button1_id
        text: "PRESS ME 2"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .8}
        on_release: app.clear()
'''

list1 = (['Item 1','Item 2','Item 3'], ['Item 4', 'Item 5', 'Item 6'])
class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.screen = Screen()
        self.btn = Builder.load_string(button)
        self.btn1 = Builder.load_string(button1)

        self.screen.add_widget(self.btn1)
        self.screen.add_widget(self.btn)


        self.drop = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller = self.btn.ids.button_id,
            items = [{'text':'Show Chips'}],
            width_mult = 4,
        )
        self.drop.bind(on_release=self.testing)

        return self.screen
    
    def testing(self, menu, menu_item):
        objects = {0.2 : "Item 1", 0.5 : "Item 2", 0.8 : "Item 3"}
        for pos, item in objects.items():
            self.chip = MDChip(
                text = item,
                check = True,
                pos_hint = {"center_x":pos, "center_y":0.4},
                
            )
            self.screen.add_widget(self.chip)

    def clear(self):
        for child in self.root.children[:]:
            if child.text in list1[0]:
                self.root.remove_widget(child)

Test().run()
```

### Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "e:\Projects\Workout Planner\Planner v_1\My_Project\Test\test.py", line 61, in <module>
     Test().run()
   File "C:\Users\Mocha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 949, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "C:\Users\Mocha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 919, in _run_prepare
     root = self.build()
   File "e:\Projects\Workout Planner\Planner v_1\My_Project\Test\test.py", line 37, in build
     caller = self.btn.ids.button_id,
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 864, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
PS E:\Projects\Workout Planner\Planner v_1\My_Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I have found a fix to the problem although I don't know the correct reason for why it wouldn't work in my code that I previously posted

### Solution:

You would have to build another class which inherits from `Screen`.
And then enter/copy everything that you want to have in your application in this new Class.

And in the Class which inherits from `MDApp` you can specify the theme you'd like to have and return the Class inheriting from Screen

Also after transferring all your widgets to the Class inheriting from `Screen` make sure you refer to this class as `root` and not `app` whenever you would be binding functions to the buttons or doing something else with it.

### Solution Code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivymd.uix.chip import MDChip
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

Builder.load_string(
    """
<BuildApp>:

    MDRaisedButton:
        id: button_id
        text: "PRESS ME"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .35, "center_y": .8}
        on_release: root.drop.open()

    MDRaisedButton:
        id: button1_id
        text: "PRESS ME 2"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .8}
        on_release: root.clear()
        
    """
)#reference should be as root.function_name(),


list1 = (['Item 1','Item 2','Item 3'], ['Item 4', 'Item 5', 'Item 6'])

class BuildApp(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.drop = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller = self.ids.button_id,   #use self.id.id_name
            items = [{'text':'Show Chips'}],
            width_mult = 4,
        )
        self.drop.bind(on_release=self.show_chips)
    
    def show_chips(self, menu, menu_item):
        objects = {0.2 : "Item 1", 0.5 : "Item 2", 0.8 : "Item 3"}
        for pos, item in objects.items():
            self.chip = MDChip(
                text = item,
                check = True,
                pos_hint = {"center_x":pos, "center_y":0.4},
                
            )
            self.add_widget(self.chip)

    def clear(self):
        for child in self.children[:]:
            if child.text in list1[0]:
                self.remove_widget(child)

class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return BuildApp()

    
    

Test().run()
```

[**Reference**](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/issues/511)